# GLSL major mode for Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp, glsl

I found this link http://artis.imag.fr/~Xavier.Decoret/resources/glsl-mode/, but there isn't a lot of description around it, aside that it's "simple".

Ideally, I'd like an extension to CcMode that can do it, or at least a mode that can handle auto-styling and has similar shortcuts to CcMode.

If there isn't one, any good elisp references to help me get started writing it myself would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: David's response prompted me to take a closer look at glsl-mode.el, and it is in fact based on cc-mode, so it's exactly what I was looking for in the first place.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add the following code to your ~/.emacs file.

```
(autoload 'glsl-mode "glsl-mode" nil t)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.vert\\'" . glsl-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.frag\\'" . glsl-mode))
```

Put the file http://artis.imag.fr/~Xavier.Decoret/resources/glsl-mode/glsl-mode.el somewhere on your emacs path.  You can eval (print load-path) in your *scratch* buffer to get the list of possible locations.  If you don't have write access to any of those, you can append another location to load-paths by adding

```
(setq load-path (cons "~/.emacs.d" load-path))
```

to your ~/.emacs file.

Comment: That's the one mentioned at the site a linked to, but I double-checked when you posted it (making the correct assumption that I didn't get all the info the first time). It's exactly what I'm looking for =)

Answer (score 3):

Based on GLSL mode, I wrote a similar one for HLSL which is used in Direct3D effect.
Here it is. http://sourceforge.net/projects/hlslmode/files/hlsl-mode.el